# Esc calibration

Tags: arduino, matlab, brushless-motor, esc, hardware

I want to make a calibration setup for BLDC ESC in the simulink model. I'm using arduino mega (3,9,10,11 pins) and quatro 30Ax4 esc. Normally I can set it to it's max, min, and incrementally increase/decrease duty cycle with transmitter throttle signal by mapping (1000,2000,160,255) and there is no problem. But when I try to map it 0,255 it doesnot work (sounds every 2 seconds like a throttle signal is abnormal).

I need two suggestions;

**1.** why I cannot map the signal on the full range (0-255).

**2.** is it possible to make calibration by just sending the max and min values such as shown in the figure instead of using any mapping techniques?

[image: Switching-Calibration]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Missing a few information, so I will assume the following:
 - Using the instruction analogWrite() to send pulses to the ESC.
 - Not using the Mega pin 4 or 13.
 - your map() instruction is converting from your receiver pulse length to your analogWrite() function.

ESC require a pulse between 1000uS and 2000uS.
Therefore, analogWrite(160) is about a 1280uS pulse.
(as per analogWrite() reference note, the PWM frequency is 490Hz)
Sending a PWM lower than 125 will send an invalid pulse length.

Some ESC wont arm if the pulse length  is off by even a few uS, so it's good to calibrate them when you do a change in your map() function.

Can't help you for your Simulink model

Comment: I wrote the pin numbers you can see them above. I amnot using arduino IDE just simulink. you mean that I cannot use full range (0-255) and my min command should be 125 and also I cannot use switching calibration procedure. right?

Comment: Why not using the Servo blocks. It will provide you the right pulse length and higher precision.
Sending a PWM value of 255 doesn't send a pulse but keep the line at HIGH. So the highest value you could send is 254.